# Mounting GlusterFS share under www-data user

Tags: linux, mount, glusterfs

**Problem:** After directory is auto-mounted, Web Server has no write permissions to it.

**Question:** How to auto-mount GlusterFS endpoint via /etc/fstab so that mount point belongs to www-data after it's mounted?

For now, the mount point belongs to www-data, but after mounting it turns to root.

```
# /etc/fstab
foo.com:/st /st glusterfs defaults 0 0
```

Seams like I cannot define user / group as mount options for GlusterFS, at least I don't see it when `man glusterfs`.

Thanks!

Comment: Resolved - dir permission are inherited from destination directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the solution is to `chown` it *after it is mounted*. Once you've mounted it, and it's back to `root:root`, chown it to what you need it to be. That should persist across remounts.

Comment: I'm creating automated DR system. Probably, if this couldn't be done over /etc/fstab, Bash could be of help... Or Udev rule.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Directory permissions are inherited from destination directory. So I just changed that and it is mounted as I wanted now.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the options below so that when the GlusterFS mount the volume
the permissions are according to your needs

- storage.owner-gid
- storage.owner-uid

Example: `gluster volume set VOL-NAME storage.owner-gid 100`